# NSManagedObject in temporary context gets faulted

Tags: swift, core-data

I've got a list of elements where editing/creation is possible, I do this in a new context and save it only if the user presses save.

My problem is now that when I'd like to handle the object to an other view controller, the properties are all nil, i.e. the user presses "new element", gets the form provided, a new ManagedObject is created in a new context and properties are set. If I provide that object to another view controller, the object is fault and all properties are nil - how can I prevent this? I don't like to save and delete it if the user presses cancel, I would prefer creation/editing on a "scratchpad context" and save it only if the user really presses save.

Comment: Do you have a strong reference to this scratchpad managed object context, or is there a chance that it is being deallocated?

Comment: wow, that hurts :) That was really the case here, silly me. If you write that as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely scenario is that your scratchpad managed object context is deallocated, and this is wiping out the managed object. Managed objects are dependent on their context but don't retain them (to avoid retain cycles), so if the context ever disappears, they stop working. Nil values for properties is the most common symptom of a missing context. For possible future reference, this is also true when the managed object has already been saved, and is not still a temporary object.